# Disable session per controller in ASP.Net Core 3.x

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

Is it possible, in ASP.NET Core 3.x to disable session related middleware per controller or method, either via Attribute or some other mechanism?

In fact, is there a generic strategy for disabling any middleware on these levels?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are ways to enable specific middleware on an endpoint, could that work for you? Then you have to setup that endpoint manually in Startup.cs, it can't exist on a controller.

Comment: Is it possible to remove specific middleware on an endpoint, or just enable?

Comment: I think you can do it by intercepting an endpoint with your own middleware and disabling a Feature, not sure though...